# Glide 4 - ModelLoader context

Tags: android, android-glide

How do we get a `context` to a custom `ModelLoader` in Glide 4?  We should not store the `context` in the `ModelLoaderFactory`

Registry requires a factory:

```
public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, Registry registry) {
    registry.append(MetadataTest.class, InputStream.class, new RawModelLoaderFactory(context));
}
```

`build` can't take a context:

```
public ModelLoader<MetadataTest, InputStream> build(@NonNull MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
    return new RawModelLoader(context);
}
```

So there's no context during the `ModelLoader` creation:

```
RawModelLoader(context)
                 ^^^ How would we get this?
```

The docs clearly mention storing a `context` in a `ModelLoader` *not* `ModelLoaderFactory`, but I can't see how one is possible without the other.  The reason I need the `context` is for the dirty god-forsaken SAF.

Comment: Not familiar with Glide . But RawModelLoader seems an implementation of ModelLoader . I think you can save Context with a constructor. Create a parametrized constructor in `RawModelLoader`.

Comment: The issue is the factory is the only thing that can be registered, so factory -> loader without storing in factory...I'm a little stumped how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Glide persists for the lifetime of the app it's fine to use the `applicationContext`.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3061